# GitLab CI build indicator in system tray possible?

Tags: system-tray, monitoring

My problem is, I work on several lengthy but urgent builds which randomly fail after some time. During this time (sometimes up to one hour!), I could focus on other work if not distracted by the need to control their status.

Is there a possibility to use a dedicated software or configure something else to have some sort of indicator icon in the system tray connected in background to GitLab API?

I could write a custom localhost backend script to provide some status data but have no idea about the desktop UI integration.